# Least number of cuts to share sausages equally

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

I found this exceptionally vague question, but I can't come up with a mathematically robust solution to it.

Give it a go if you have the time!

> (i) Find the least number of cuts required to cut 12 identical sausages so that they can be shared equally among 18 people
>
> (ii) Find the least number of cuts, in terms of m and n, required to cut m identical sausages so that they can be shared equally among n people.

The question does not specify that:

1. A cut applies to all sausages
2. The resulting length of each sausage must be the same

So the resulting solution for part (i) would be 12 cuts:

- Cutting each sausage at the 2/3 mark
- Giving 12 people a 2/3 piece of sausage each, and the rest 2 x 1/3 piece

Assuming this obscure way of understanding the question, what would be the solution for (ii)?

[I'm thinking that there exist an M and N such that you will require M x N cuts to split equally (a proof by contradiction) but I can't find such a M and N, neither can I formulate a proof by induction for (ii)]

Comment: If one person can have more than one sausage, then the least number of cuts is just one.

Comment: It says the resulting length of each  sausage must be the same.What does this mean?  The same as what?

Comment: @Goldname, the sausages must be shared equally among all, so if you have 5 sausages and 3 people, each person will get more than 1 sausage, but you'll need 2 cuts.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, the question did not specify the length of each sausage must be the same after cutting, which is a typically of a LCF/LCM question.

Comment: I know but I was still wondering what it might mean even though it's not required.  I suppose it means you can cut any way you want.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet yup, so assuming you can cut any way you want, how would you answer (ii)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always do it with $N-1$ cuts.  Imagine lining the sausages up, then cut off $\frac MN$ for each person.  The number of cuts can be reduced if some of them come at the sausage boundaries.  In your $M=12, N=18$ example five of the sausage boundaries are where you want to cut, so instead of $17$ cuts you only need $12$.  You should be able to convince yourself that you can always reduce the number by $\gcd(M,N)-1$, which in your example is $5$.  This proves you can get the cuts down to that, it doesn't prove you can't do even better.

In your $12,18$ problem I could claim that I can do it with one cut.  Line up all the sausages side by side and make one cut across all of them at the $\frac 23$ point, then distribute the pieces as you suggested.